# react-native run-android build successful but Does not work with Access Denied

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio-code, react-native

I'm a developer developing react-native using VSC on Windows. The build succeeds, but it turns out not to run

The react-native run-android command printed BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

But unfortunately in the next line
Access is denied.

[image]

With only a message, the app is installed on the device, but it doesn't run. When I run it, I see the make sure blabla error screen that appears when there is no node server.

This problem eliminated my two days.
I want to get help.

Ps. Note that project asd is a new project for testing. If you look at the existing project and test project, I guess it might be Java configuration, but ... I am suffering because there is no proper solution.

Comment: You could start the node server manually by running "npm start" or "yarn start" in your project directory and reload the app.

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir  I want to Debugging in vsc. Is there any way to build in vsc?

Comment: to get native logs from the android phone, I think you need logcat in android studio. But you dont need to use android studio to build or run your app

Comment: running "react-native run-android" builds your app in debug mode using the "gradlew" command and the runs it on the connected device/emulator.
You could do the same in the command line

Comment: Is it possible that your phone blocks the installation somehow. And did you try to run powershell with admin privileges?

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir powershell ran as administrator. But it doesn't build. I tried npm start But "BUNDLE [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (969/969), done." Stopped at
Try react-native run-android in new powershell. No response Didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you provide more info like react-native version, node version and your android build gradle?

Comment: Of course. This is the versions. 
react-native Version -> [ react-native-cli: 2.0.1 , react-native: 0.59.9]
node Version -> [ v12.11.1 ]
npm Version -> [ 6.11.3 ]
android gradle plugin Version -> [ 3.5.1 ]
gradle Version -> [ 5.4.1 ]

Comment: I tried creating a new project. But the same result. The same is true for new projects that touch nothing. I be urgently needed help

Comment: Were you able to build before with this environment? Are you testing it on your phone or android emulator? If you test it on your phone, make sure usb debbuging is on and the app is not somehow blocked by your phone.

Comment: Can you test it with another phone or emulator?

Comment: I test on the device. Do not use the emulator. One day, it happened suddenly. I was developing the app under normal testing in the same environment.